# Bootstrap - nav active/hover class color change via CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple question about navigation top-fixed. I want to change color of class active and make hover for others positions (About us etc).

I want to do it in my custom main.css (not bootstrap) but I don't have any ideas how to make it works.

Here is preview website: http://tester-web.web44.net/

Comment: Post your code here. Nobody wants to go to your website.

Comment: Here is my code index.html http://wklej.org/id/1088427/ and CSS http://wklej.org/id/1088428/

Comment: Post them in the question.

Comment: This is a perfect example why markup and code is to be placed here and not a third party site as the example in the question no longer exists which makes this question and any answers useless.

Answer (score 0):

```
nav a:link, nav a:visited, nav a:active { color: blue; }
nav a:hover { color: yellow; }
nav a.active { color: red; }
```

*note* The a:active only applies while the link is being pressed/focused.

Comment: Hmmm, well it doesn't work for me. I had added your code and same nothing changed.

Comment: @Rusek - does your fixed menu consist of a NAV tag with A tags inside of it? If not the above CSS will not work. Also you should learn to use Firebug (or even inspect element) in Firefox and Chrome browser. They will show you the current active CSS and computed values.

Comment: Yes, I know this because I use Chrome, so it's ok, but it seems to me that with CSS is something wrong. When I change color by webkit it works but CSS not. http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/2034/vmqq.png